# 64 Bit Free Anti Virus

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, anti-virus

> **Related Question**
>   [Free Antivirus solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)

I am looking for a free native 64 Bit Anti virus package. I know lots / nearly all packages will run in 32bit emulated mode, but I can't seem to find a truly native 64 bit package, that's free. Anyone?

Comment: For Windows 7, presumably?

Comment: @Jonik:  Presumably.  All of JL's other questions seem to be about Windows / Windows 7.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate since all the Windows AV programs listed on the mentioned question run both 32Bit and 64Bit. However I am allowing it as it is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Antivirus/Microsoft-Security-Essentials.shtml)

Link is to Softpedia. It's in beta right now but I've been using it for about a month and so far it works great. It has a 64bit version.

Comment: Would you trust it enough to do away with your traditional AV product? Not really sure if I'm ready to trust MS with an AV product, but I could be wrong?

Comment: I already did. I used Kaspersky AV before. I don't think Microsoft is very new in the AV "game". Their paid OneCare app was pretty decent from the tests I read. It seems like they improved on that and got to a very nice product. You really should try it.

Comment: I have marked this answer as accepted, because out of all the answers, its the only fully fledged 64bit solution.

Comment: And yeah - I've downloaded it, and it seems a very well polished solution. I'll be reading more reviews about it, but from what I've read so far it's a competitive AV solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used [AVAST](http://www.avast.com/eng/x64.html) and never had any problems. The link provides you information on a 64BIT AVAST.

Answer (score 1):

A good site for x64 software is http://www.start64.com.

you'll certainly find some trailware in the security page: http://www.start64.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=53&Itemid=117

They don't list any known free anti virus scanner as 64bit native.

Comment: Thanks Davy , yes unfortunately they don't but lots of other cool stuff there...

Answer (score 1):

[AVG Free Antivirus](http://free.avg.com/).

Here's a snapshot in Process Explorer.  While *some* of its processes are 32-bit, the important one -- **avgrsa.exe**, which is the resident shield that scans accessed files -- is a native 64-bit process.  The proof's here:

[image: AVG processes]

Anyway, I wouldn't get too hung up on *everything* you run being 64-bit.  It's often not necessary, and the performance difference is negligible for most applications.

(By the way, I own a registered version of AVG and I also didn't include all of the options during install, so what you see may not reflect *exactly* what you'd see in the process list for the free version of AVG.)

Comment: the reason you'd want a 64bit virus scanner is that else the activities of your 64bit process (such as explorer) would not be scanned...

Comment: Good point and well-said - I should have elaborated when I said "the important one" above :-)