# Is there any free anti-virus software?

Tags: anti-virus

Is there any free anti-virus software?

I am using a PC which is Window 7. I am seeking a free, powerful and lightweight anti-virus software.

Comment: There was a similar question in the past that was deleted [see meta post on the topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4381/undelete-the-list-of-free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows) - also see [this older question](http://superuser.com/questions/35989/64-bit-free-anti-virus) - there's no obvious research attempt in the question

Answer (score 4):

2 High Quality & Free Antivirus softwares that I've been using on my laptop with Win 7 ;

**1-** [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/tr-TR/windows/products/security-essentials) : You can download & use MS Security Essentials for free without any time limitation if you have Windows operating system on your PC

[image: MS Security Essentials Screenshot]

**2-** [AVG Antivirus Free](http://www.freeavg.com/?lng=tr-en&cmpid=free) : One of my favourite free software.I had bought KIS 2011 license but after expiration I've been using AVG Antivirus free, it's stable for home users.

[image: AVG Antivirus Screenshot]